# Error al exportar clase

Tags: javascript

Tengo dos archivos en la **misma carpeta**, uno llamada `main.js` y el otro `es.js`.

El problema es que al intentar importar una clase de `es.js` , **desde** `main.js` me lanza el error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

**main.js :**

```
    import ES from './es.js';
```

**es.js**

```
   class ES{
    constructor(){
    get(symbol, e){
    let d = document;
    return symbol === "#" ? d.getElementById(e) : symbol === "." ? d.getElementsByClassName(e) : d.getElementsByTagName(e);
    }   
    }
}

export default ES;
```

Answer (score 5):

La razón es que el navegador que estás utilizando para ejecutar ese código aún no tiene soporte para ES modules. Puedes ver una tabla de compatibilidad [en Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module).

Existen herramientas que son utilizadas mucho cuando se programa en ES6, ES7, ES8 o incluso con APIs experimentales y/o en desarrollo. Una de estas herramientas es [Babel](https://babeljs.io).

Esta herramienta te permite, a través de [presets y plugins](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation), transpilar un código escrito en ES6+ a uno ES5 (entendible por todos los navegadores), también puedes usar otras herramientas como [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com) o [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org) junto con Babel para hacer este proceso de forma automática y además generar un *bundle*, que es simplemente el código ya transpilado, concatenado, optimizado y minificado.